# How to print only a certain part of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I wanted to get a certain part of a list to print what would I have to do?

Here is an example; say that:

```
list = [DOG, CAT, LION, TIGER, CAT, DOG, LION, LION, TIGER]
```

and I want it to just print the instances where it starts with CAT and stops at TIGER. So from the above list I want to add the first instance CAT, LION, TIGER to a list, and the second instance CAT, DOG, LION, LION, TIGER to another list. so there is going to be 2 lists where:

```
list1 = [CAT, LION]
```

and

```
list2 = [CAT, DOG, LION, LION]
```

So is there a way for me to split the list up to a certain point?

Comment: Loop through, check if each item is CAT, if it is, get the index. Continue looping for TIGER, if it is, get the index. You now have the indices for the first CAT -> TIGER - which you can use to create a new list. Then start looping for the next CAT, etc. etc.

Comment: Have you tried looping once through the elements of the list and building your lists like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [algorithm recommended in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799690/how-to-print-only-a-certain-part-of-a-list/46800149#comment80546315_46799690):

```
my_list = ['DOG', 'CAT', 'LION', 'TIGER', 'CAT', 'DOG', 'LION', 'LION', 'TIGER']

# get the indicies of each element 'CAT' from the list
cat_indicies = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "CAT"]

# list comprehension for all elements between first and second instance of 'CAT'
my_list1 = [my_list[i] for i in range(*cat_indicies)]

# list of all elements starting from second instance of 'CAT'
my_list2 = my_list[cat_indicies[-1]::]

print(my_list1)  # ['CAT', 'LION', 'TIGER']
print(my_list2)  # ['CAT', 'DOG', 'LION', 'LION', 'TIGER']
```

note the lists result from *requirements* mentioned in the question, and do not necessarily match the example lists *suggested* in the question

Comment: and I have an idea now of how I can implement this into my code!